# dajax.core ImportError at /No module named

Tags: dajaxice

I've installed dajaxice by [this tutorial](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/installation.html):

- Copied folder "dajaxice" (from archive) to project folder.
- Added all changes to setting.py & urls.py
- Added next lines to template:

  ```
  {% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
  {% dajaxice_js_import %}
  ```
- Created `ajax.py` in the project folder
- Code from `ajax.py`:

  ```
  from django.utils import simplejson
  from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_functions

  @dajaxice_register
  def example1(request):
      return simplejson.dumps({'message': 'hello world'})

  dajaxice_functions.register(example1)
  ```
- Code from .js file:

  ```
  $("#id_submit").click(function(){
      Dajaxice.theproject.example1(callback_example);
      console.log("test clicked");
      return false; });
  ```
- When I restart the project in browser at first request I got:

  ```
  ImportError at / No module named dajax.core
  Request Method: GET
  Request URL:    http:// 127.0.0.1:8000/
  Django Version: 1.4
  Exception Type: ImportError
  Exception Value:     No module named dajax.core
  Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module, line 37
  Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
  Python Version: 2.7.3
  Python Path:     ['E:\\Projects\\py\\sites\\theproject',  'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',  'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',  'C:\\Python27\\lib',  'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',  'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',  'C:\\Python27',  'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',  'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
  Server time:    Fri, 3 Aug 2012 14:50:03 +0300
  ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load ajax.py in init.py(of main app)

Answer (score 0):

Dajaxice is updating all the time. Make sure you have downloaded and installed the correct version of Dajax for the document you are reading. In your error message, it says, "No module named dajax.core", which is probably because you are using the wrong version.

And the current version of Dajaxice and Dajax can be found here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dajax

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dajaxice/0.5.5